# openpyxl Iterate down column and apply formula, skip first row

Tags: python-3.x, excel-formula, openpyxl

Using openpyxl, I'm trying to apply a formula for each row in a column on an excel sheet. I also need to skip the first row.

The below code works. However, it overwrites the first row which is my header row.

```py
for row, cellObj in enumerate(list(ws.columns)[5]):
    #print(cellObj)
    n = '=(D%d*E%d)' % (row, row)
    cellObj.value = n
```

How can I achieve the current results without overwriting the first row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an if statement. The if statement checks what the row number is. If it is not zero you add the formula.

```
if row != 0:
        n = '=(D%d*E%d)' % (row, row)
        cellObj.value = n
```

Comment: This solved my issue, thank you. However, it raises a new issue. The formula is a cell behind. By this I mean that '=D2*E2' puts the total in cell F3 and so on down the column.

Comment: Just add +1 to the row. `n = '=(D%d*E%d)' % (row+1, row+1)`

Comment: Your nailed it!